# Как разместит меню в центре?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.headdiv {
    width: 150%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.companylogo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 95px;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -120px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding:  0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    float: right;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 40px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#Home"> Home </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#About"> About </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Services"> Services </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Projects"> Projects </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Contact"> Contact </a></li>
                    </ul>
            <div class="companylogo" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: li{ float: right; } - размещает элементы справа.
Попробуйте ul {display: flex; text-align: center;}
Кроме того, смущает ширина в 150% - .headdiv {width: 150%;... }

Comment: Уже разместил в центре но сейчас хочу двигать все это пикселями. Пробовал padding и margin (left,right) но ничего не получается.

Comment: ul {display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;} - например.

Answer (score 1):

```
.headdiv {
    width: 150%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.companylogo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 95px;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -120px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:  0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Вот так работает

Comment: Спасибо большое !